ADB command to set microphone always on
I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab S8+, and the microphone is disabled whenever I switch from Discord to the home screen (only if the screen stream is on).
I've tried almost every possible way except using ADB commands to set my microphone as "always" since there is no such option in settings.
So, is there a way to set the microphone always on for Discord via ADB commands?

By "settings" you mean Android settings or Discord settings?

android settings

Please edit your post to include the model number/year and OS version that the device is running (Samsung has a tendency to use similar names). Also identify how you are connecting to discord (app/web).

Opposite of How to make Discord Android app to stop using microphone when it's not active or closed? and How to stop microphone or app on screen lock?. Did you enable all notifications for Discord? Otherwise, did you see a notification about Discord VC when switching to the home screen?

yes,i see VC notification,and all notifications are enabled..ill look at them,thanks!
